# Adapting to OR Adapting with

Tags: prepositions, slogan

I wish to have a slogan for a software company. The slogan that I thought of is something like

> "Adapting **to** your Changes"

What I want to say with that slogan is, our company adapts well with the changes in requirements of the customers.

Is it supposed to be "Adapting **with** your Changes" instead?

Comment: You may ask one question per post. Questions related to grammar and usage are the usual stuff on ELU. For creative writing ideas, try writersSE. No need to say 'Thanks' -- vote the answers as they come up, instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind and  your comment worth a vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way anyone but you can say what your slogan **is supposed** to be.

The usual preposition for *adapt* is *to*: *X adapts to Y*, meaning something adapts in response to some external stimulus. Your customers' circumstances change, and you adapt accordingly.

Changing the preposition to *with* has two effects:

- It's unusual, so it attracts attention and consideration;
- It brings your adapting alongside your customers' changes, rather than lagging behind them. It's collaborative rather than reactive.

Whether you want to use the word *changes* could bear consideration. Using *changes* might be seen as implying that you consider your customers as fickle, perhaps even not foreseeing consequences and constantly changing to correct mistakes. Perhaps you might use the word ***needs*** there:

> Adapting with your needs

This trusts your clients with more foresight and analysis into what they actually need; and using ***with*** indicates that you can actually **help** rather than simply react.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was an wonderful explanation. Changing to "Adapting with your Needs" :-)

Comment: @TheKojuEffect Jolly good. I'll send the consultancy bill along in due course :-)

Comment: Just received your bill, You'll receive your payment as soon as you get it.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition that goes with *adapt* is generally, *to*.

*Adapting **to** your changes* is fine.

Although the idea of "keeping pace with changes and adapting as required from time to time" that you seem to want to convey is understandable, "keeping pace with" and "adapting" are two distinct things. The preposition applies to *adapt* alone.

The phrase *Adapt **with** change* is sometimes, though only rarely, used, in a rather different sense: perhaps, meaning adapt to something with a change in something else.

You may want to rephrase the sentence suitably, which is a different story.